# Grab 'n' numbers from a given list of numbers with minimum difference between them

Tags: python, arrays

I put up a similar question a few hours ago, albeit with a few mistakes, and my poor understanding, admittedly
So the question is, from a given list of indefinite numbers, I'm supposed to take an input from the user, say 3, and grab 3 numbers wherein the numbers have the least difference between them.

```
def findMinDiff(arr): 
    # Initialize difference as infinite 
    diff = 10**20
    n = len(arr)
# Find the min diff by comparing difference 
# of all possible pairs in given array 
    for i in range(n-1): 
        for j in range(i+1,n): 
            if abs(arr[i]-arr[j]) < diff: 
                diff = abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) 
    # Return min diff 
    return diff 

def findDiffArray(arr):
    diff = 10**20
    arr_diff = []
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
            arr_diff.append(abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1]))
    return arr_diff

def choosingElements(arr, arr_diff):
    arr_choose = []
    least_index = 0
    least = arr_diff[0]
    least_index_array = []
    flag = 0
    flag2 = 0
    for z in range(0,3):
        for i in range(0,len(arr_diff)-1):
        
            if arr_diff[i] < least:
                if flag > 0:
                    if i == least_index:
                        continue 
                least = arr_diff[i]
                least_index = i 
                least_index_array.append(i)
                arr_choose.append(arr[i])
                flag += 1 
                arr_choose.append(arr[i+1])
                flag += 1 
    print("least index is", least_index)
    return arr_choose   
# Driver code 
arr = [1, 5, 3, 19, 18, 25] 
arr_diff =  findDiffArray(arr)
arr_diff2 = arr_diff.copy()
item_number = int(input("Enter the number of gifts"))
arr_choose = choosingElements(arr, arr_diff2)
print("Minimum difference is " + str(findMinDiff(arr)))
print("Difference array")
print(*arr_diff, sep = "\n") 
print("Numbers with least difference for specified items are", arr_choose)
```

This is how much I've tried, and I've thought to find the difference between numbers, and keep picking ones with the least difference between them, and I realised that my approach is probably wrong.

Can anybody kindly help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You have to choose the nearest numbers to the mean.

Comment: Could you give example input and expected output? Not sure I understand the question. Also, a list indefinite numbers?

Comment: @GioviQ I just tried this. I don't think that would work too?

Comment: @RolvApneseth Yes I will try creating an example and putting it up again 
Also, yes indefinite numbers, it could be 10 or 100

Comment: by `wherein the numbers have the least difference between them`do  you mean in consecutive order or do you mean reordering elements is needed?

Comment: @deadvoid No, not consecutive order, anything would do, but in the end they're supposed to have minimum difference

Comment: that's an important distinction, you should include it in your question

Comment: input: 1, 18, 5, 19, 25, 3. Mean: 11,83. Diffs: 10.83, 6.17, 6.83, 7.17, 13.17, 8,83. Output: 18, 5, 19, 3, 1, 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I'm sure the time complexity on this isn't great, and it might be hard to understand, but how about this:

```
arr = [1, 18, 5, 19, 25, 3]


# calculates length of the overall path
def calc_path_difference(arr, i1, i2, i3):
    return abs(arr[i1] - arr[i2]) + abs(arr[i2] - arr[i3])


# returns dictionary with differences to other numbers in arr from each number
def differences_dict(arr):
    return {
        current: [
            abs(number - current) if abs(number - current) != 0 else float("inf")
            for number in arr
        ]
        for current in arr
    }


differences = differences_dict(arr)
# Just to give some starting point, take the first three elements of arr
current_path = [calc_path_difference(arr, 0, 1, 2), 0, 1, 2]

# Loop 1
for i, num in enumerate(arr):
    # Save some time by skippin numbers who's path
    # already exceeds the min path we currently have
    if not min(differences[num]) < current_path[0]:
        continue

    # Loop 2
    for j, num2 in enumerate(arr):
        # So you can't get 2 of the same index
        if j == i:
            continue

        # some code for making indices i and j of differences 
        # infinite so they can't be the smallest, but not sure if
        # this is needed without more tests
        # diff_arr_copy = differences[num2].copy()
        # diff_arr_copy[i], diff_arr_copy[j] = float("inf"), float("inf")

        # Get index of number in arr with smallest difference to num2
        min_index = differences[num2].index(min(differences[num2]))

        # So you can't get 2 of the same index again
        if min_index == i or min_index == j:
            continue

        # Total of current path
        path_total = calc_path_difference(arr, i, j, min_index)

        # Change current path if this one is shorter
        if path_total < current_path[0]:
            current_path = [path_total, i, j, min_index]
```

Does this work for you? I played around with the order of the elements in the array and it seemed to give the correct output each time but I would have liked to have another example to test it on.